# Is there any way to deduce whether this function is a class static function according to the function name

Tags: c++, macros, c++14, template-meta-programming, type-deduction

I want to get the type of this function by function name, such as class static function, class non static member function, extern C function, etc. Can it be realized through Template Meta Programming or similar methods?

If I cannot do that at the compile time, is it possible at the run time? Thanks in advance.

```cpp
extern "C" {
    void cFunction() { ... }
}

void normalFunction() { ... }

class MyClass
{
public:
    static void staticMemberFunction() { ... }
    void nonStaticMemberFunction() { ... }
};

// SOME_MACRO is what I want
SOME_MACRO(cFunction);  // print "C"
SOME_MACRO(normalFunction);  // print "normal"
SOME_MACRO(MyClass, staticMemberFunction);  // print "class static"
SOME_MACRO(MyClass, nonStaticMemberFunction);  // print "class non static"
```

Comment: What is the *actual* and *underlying* problem that your macro would solve? Please ask about that directly instead, because right now your question is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: `decltype(&MyClass::Func)` would be either `void(MyClass::*)()` or `void (*)()`, so you might differentiate static member functions from regular member functions.

Comment: `extern "C"` doesn't change signature of function, just its mangling name...